# Excel VBA - struggling to create macros which takes action on cell values by column

Tags: vba, excel

Very new to Excel VBA, and struggling.
I'm a junior C# developer, but am finding that writing simple statements in VBA is very tricky for me. 
 Can anyone tell me how to write VBA code for the following pseudocode requirements please?

1. Insert **True** into Column E only WHERE there is a specific string value of **X** in column A
2. Insert **False** into Column E WHERE there is text (ie: something/anything) in column D AND no text (ie: nothing) in Column A
3. Delete **X** wherever there is a specific string value **X** in any cell in Column A.

Any help at all would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: Tried to write If statements for 1A and 1B, they didn't work. I can't even find good simple VBA basics only to tell me how exactly you write a WHERE condition. Also, I can only find info on how to specify an exact cell (Range("A3")) or a block of cells (Range("A3:A100")), but not simply 'any cell in A which has a specific string (not number) value'. Help please!

Comment: A good place to start is the [language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338033(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm pushed for time, but will do my best with this.

Comment: Still hoping for some code suggestions anyone!

Comment: Hi Siddarth. Unfortunately this needs to be written in VBA because it needs to be run on spreadsheets in this format for the next few months, and the different sheets will all have different cell values (although the spreadsheet structure in terms of columns etc will always be the same).

Comment: Siddharth's suggestion is a valid one. Record a marco is not the absolute answer but it does write VBA code for you. You would need to tailor that to your needs but its a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub Text_Process()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim strColA As String
    Dim strColD As String

    lngLastRow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For lngRow = 1 To lngLastRow ' change 1 to 2 if you have headings in row 1
        strColA = Sheet1.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value ' store value in column A
        strColD = Sheet1.Cells(lngRow, 4).Value ' store value of column D

        Sheet1.Cells(lngRow, 5).Clear ' clear column E

        If strColA = "X" Then ' or whatever you are looking for
            Sheet1.Cells(lngRow, 5).Value = True
        ElseIf strColA = "" And strColD <> "" Then
            Sheet1.Cells(lngRow, 5).Value = False
        End If

        If strColA = "X" Then ' or whatever you are looking for
            Sheet1.Cells(lngRow, 1).Clear ' clear out the value in column A, is this is what is requried?
        End If



    Next lngRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi user - your solution works perfectly. Thank you so so much! I really appreciate you taking this time, wonderful help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's basic stuff do to. VBA has basically the same syntax of VB 6.

You can read the [language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338033(v=vs.60).aspx) or hitting F1 on VBA editor for help.

Just for example, check this code. Besides your requirements are a bit confusing, pay attention in the code structure and the functions used, like `Range.Cells`, `IsEmpty`

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim limit, index As Integer

    ' Iterate limit, just for test
    limit = 20

    ' Iterate your worksheet until the limit
    For i = 1 To limit Step 1

        ' Range param is a string, you can do any string contatenation you wish
        ' Value property is what inside the cell

        If (Not IsEmpty(Range("D" & i).Value) And IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value)) Then
            ' Requirement 2
            Range("E" & i).Value = False

        ElseIf (Range("A" & i).Value = "X") Then
            ' Requiriment 1
            Range("E" & i).Value = True

            ' Requiriment 3
            Range("A" & i).Value = Empty
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Like Siddharth said, recording a macro and study the generated code is a great way to learn some VBA tricks.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance gm, it was very nice of you.